# Auto add space and / when I press space bar in excel 2003

Tags: excel, macros, space

I want to write a macro in Excel so every time I hit space bar (when I'm in column  I ) I want to automatically send "space slash and space again".

I press space bar on my keyboard and as result I get space slash space.

I want this to happen ONLY when im in cell on column I.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro to replace spaces with space-slash-space when the value that has changed resides within column I.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(9)) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim rng As Range
        For Each rng In Intersect(Target, Columns(9))
            'make safe anything that already has been changed
            rng = Replace(rng.Value2, " / ", ChrW(8203))
            'change new spaces
            rng = Chr(39) & Replace(rng.Value2, Chr(32), " / ")
            'try to repait Excel's auto-date-conversion
            If IsDate(rng) Then Application.Undo
            'restore the safeties
            rng = Replace(rng.Value2, ChrW(8203), " / ")
        Next rng
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It is always a good idea to supply some sample data. I had some trouble with Excel auto-converting the transformed value into a date and had to resort to a little 'bandaiding' by applying Application.Undo on the autocorrect. It may be better to attempt to temporarily shut off the auto-correct or it may not be necessary at all.

Alternately, a [Workbook_SheetChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196611.aspx) event macro could make the process more global across the workbook and worksheet names could be filtered to accept the process of not.

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            If Target.Column = Range("I:I").Column Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Target.Value = Replace(Target.Value, " ", " / ")
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

The above code will convert the spaces as you described after pressing the enter button only. It will not replace the space when you are in editing mode.